# How to exclude the images directory in a redirect source in NextJS

Tags: regex, next.js

I followed [this tutorial](https://ruud.je/blog/redirect-ie11-nextjs/) which is perfect for my NextJS website.
The problem is my `unsupported.html` file has images in it. The images 404 because according to the redirects everything except unsupported.html will redirect (including the images).

So here is Chrome vs IE. So Chrome works because I manually went there and it won't redirect anything because it's not IE.

How can I add to this part `source: '/:path((?!unsupported.html$).*)',` to say don't redirect unsupported.html AND anything in the /public/images/ folder?

Thanks
This feels close

`source: '/:path((?!unsupported.html|.*images*$).*)',`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for your site?

```
source: '/:path((?!unsupported\.html$|images/).*)',
```

The key bit is dropping the `$` anchor from after `images`, so it doesn't have to (not) match the actual image name

Comment: Hmm no still not working unfortunately, same result. An image should have the url `http://localhost:3000/images/oops_face.png` for example. Tried without public and nada sorry

Comment: Got it without the first slash and just `images/`, thanks

Comment: @MomasVII oh right, that's dumb on my part.  I'll update the answer for future readers